# Nuxt3 AWS Lambda deployment with CodePipeline and CloudFormation error in .output/public directory

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to deploy a Nuxt3 app on AWS Lambda through a CodePipeline/CodeBuild `buildspec.yml` that runs a CloudFormation stack template. Here's a part of `template/staging.yml` that sets up the AWS Lambda

```yaml
FrontendLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ../.output
      Handler: server/index.handler
```

I used the `NITRO_PRESET=aws-lambda npm run build` to create the AWS Lambda compatible build which exports the main handler in `server/index.mjs` file.

While the build gets successful, when I try to open the API gateway endpoint hooked to the Lambda, I see the HTML content without any CSS and see errors like

```bash
https://my-api-endpoint-url.amazonaws.com/_nuxt/entry-5a589e33.mjs net::ERR_ABORTED 403
```

It says forbidden but not sure what should I change to make it accessible. Apparently, this has been happening for all the files under `.output/public` folder.

When I do `NITRO_PRESET=node-server npm run build` locally and then run `npx nuxt preview`, it loads on `http://localhost` completely fine with proper CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it fixed based on this GitHub comment:
https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/3586#issuecomment-1095695526

As stated, the `aws-lambda` nitro preset does not support serving static files. This is probably by design, because AWS API Gateway does not support serving binary files by default.

I went with the (second) option of serving the files inside `.output/public` directory separately by putting them on an S3 bucket and making that bucket public.

A simple `aws s3 sync` command in the buildspec.yml worked that would push the new compiled assets to the S3 bucket every time there was a new build.

Once this was working, I switched to a CloudFront distribution to serve these static assets and blocked the public access on the S3 bucket.